# Помогите разобраться с тире.

Tags: пунктуация

Есть у меня такие условия, которые я не понимаю.

Как ставить тире в неполном предложении?

У меня написано в учебнике следующие схемы: кто-чему, кто-куда, что - куда,  что -как, что - где.

Что эта за условия вообще? Приведите примеры и объясните, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Среди неполных предложений выделяются особый вид - эллиптические предложения.

Эллиптическими называются предложения особого построения, состоящие из подлежащего и дополнения или обстоятельства (сказуемое в таких предложениях всегда отсутствует). В эллиптических предложениях постановка тире зависит от наличия паузы. Обычно пауза делается в различных описаниях, когда выделяется первая часть предложения,  и не делается в поэтической речи:

Тихо в комнате просторной, а за окнами – мороз (где - что).    Илюша – к воротам (кто - куда), но из окна слышится голос матери.    Так вот в чём прелесть полёта в небо! Она – в паденье (что - в чем)! Смелый к победе стремится, смелым – дорога вперёд (кому - что).

Но:  Снова в час ночной тучи над землёй. Посреди небесных тел лик луны туманный.   И в жёнах, дочерях к мундирам та же страсть.

Многие эллиптические предложения имеют параллельную структуру с особой интонацией. Обычно в этом случае тире ставится, но бывают  исключения:
   Здесь – овраги, дальше – степи. На полу – ковры, над столом – красивый абажур. Во всех окнах – любопытные, на крышах – мальчишки. Тёркин – дальше, автор – вслед. 
Но:   Татьяна в лес, медведь за нею.

Эллиптические предложения следует отличать от сходных с ними по структуре назывных предложений, в которых вторая часть является не обстоятельством, а обстоятельственным определением:
   Ночь. Тишина. Сияние звёзд на тёмном небе.  Цепи синих гор в лучах солнца, туман над долинами.